# Given a grammar, how to find a valid AST for an incomplete string?

Tags: algorithm, parsing, grammar, tokenize

Is there a known algorithm that returns a possible syntax tree for a given grammar and trimmed input ?

For instance, when given the grammar of JSON and the input `",1`, a valid output would be
the syntax tree for `["", 1]`, because this is a valid JSON syntax tree, and `",1` is a substring of `["",1]`. `",1"` would also be a valid output.

Given a simple mathematical expression grammar and the string `1)-`, it could output `(1)-0`, because it is a valid expression that contains the substring `1)-`.

Comment: You might be able to modify the CYK parsing algorithm to find parses that are consistent with a given fragment.

Comment: Trying to parse a substring of practical languages can be real trouble if the substring splits a complex literal value such as quoted string or nested comment, because you aren't sure if the substring to parse begins with a literal fragment.   OP's example of  ",1 is an interesting case; you can argue for ["",1]  but you can also argue for [",1"].  To avoid this difficulty, you should probably consider defining the langauge grammar in terms of individual characters.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a heuristic than an algorithm since I don't have a proof of correctness handy. It also assumes you have an actual LR parser for the grammar. (Which places certain limitations on the grammar, obviously. But that seems like a reasonable assumption, since the problem statement more or less implies that you have some mechanism to parse complete sentences.)

Then you can run the parser on the input until you get to the last input token. If the parser reaches an error action before it consumes the last input symbol then the input is not a prefix of any valid sentence, so you can report failure. (You could try to find a similar string which is a prefix of a valid sentence, but that's well outside of the scope of this question.) If you end up in a state with an accept action on the end-of-input marker, then you already have a valid parse, so there is no need to continue. Otherwise do the following until you reach a state with an accept action on the end-of-input marker:

- If the state has one or more reduce actions, take one of them.
- Otherwise, chose some shift action available in the state, and output the shifted token as a completion token. Then take the transition indicated in the shift action.

The above doesn't indicate how to choose between available reduce or shift actions. It shouldn't make too much difference which reduce action you pick, but if you consistently choose the wrong shift action you could end up in an endless loop. Making a randomised choice is probably the simplest reasonably safe strategy.

Comment: This is missing what to do in the case that it is a substring of a valid expression but not a prefix. I would add that in that case, you're going to have to look into the language a little bit. If we are only dealing with numbers, parentheses, and binary operators, one could probably just slip a zero in front of incomplete leading binary operators, and match all parentheses. Not a proof, of course.

Comment: @JerryHalisberry: yes, good point. I should have looked more closely at the examples. For a Dyck language (or functional equivalent), it's easy, and both the examples fit that pattern. But in the general case, it's harder. Although I think it's possible, because the set of substrings of a CFG is a CFG.